# Problems with IntelliJ at cloning repo from github

Tags: java, git, maven, github, intellij-idea

I am new to github. I tried to clone a repo and then pull the files on my computer. All the other team members did the same thing and it worked for them. When i open the project with Intellij all the .java files look like this:
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WREbz.png)

It also says that my SDK isn't set.
I tried to set my SDK, and also i tried to set the java directory as 'sources root' because someone said that is a problem with the project structure.

These problems disappeared but then IntelliJ didn't recognize that my project is a maven project so i had to add manually the file pom.xml and refresh maven.

Then this problem disappeared but i had another:

```
"Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module 'cmsiss'.
Specify the output path in Configure Project."
```

I tried to set it from project structure but now I have this error:[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4X7s.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open maven project using pom.xml file. File->Open->pom.xml
2. Sources should be pointed to project root, not java directory.

Give these a try.

Answer (score 0):

The usual steps that I follow to open the project:

```
git clone <github clone url>
```

Open the project in intelli J using

```
File<Open
```

and browse to open the root of the project.

This should work fine but if it does not, a few more things you can try:

- Try making the project root as a maven module
- You can open the Project Structure to make sure you have Java SDK set up properly. It should show the java version you are using there.
- Worst case, that is if nothing else works and if the project is not too big, just create a new maven project and make sure it runs, then add all the project files.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the project again and started from zero. I specified the SDK and then I opened the Maven project window and added a maven project (selected the pom.xml file) and refreshed it. Maven did it's job and created the project structure and all the stuff I've tried to do manually and finally worked!